# Is limit about functions?

Tags: calculus, limits

When talking about limit subject, all the time we point functions. But in derivative definition we use $\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta X}$. Is $\frac{\Delta Y}{\Delta X}$ a kind of function? I have this question about integral formula as well.

Comment: $h\mapsto\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is a function, and the derivative of a function $f$ at $x$ is the limit of this function as $h\to0$

Comment: When we use $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ it is understood that $y=f(x)$.

Comment: @FShrike Thanks alot. what about this: $\Sigma f(x)dx$ for Integrals? Is this a function also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $\Delta Y/\Delta X$ is a kind of limit. So is the integral.
But there are some nuances that can make this confusing.

$\Delta Y/\Delta X$ is an older, traditional notation. This can be helpful
but also confusing. That's why many modern treatments use something
like
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
instead. Here, $f$ is the function $X\mapsto Y$ (so $Y=f(X)$), $h=\Delta X$,
and $\Delta Y=f(x+h)-f(x)$. The newer notation makes explicit the function $f$.
It also gives us the expression $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ to parse.

Strictly speaking, $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ is a function of *two* variables:
$x$ and $h$. We could write it $D(x,h)=(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$. It is undefined
when $h=0$. If we pick a particular value for $x$ and let $h$ vary, then
it becomes a function of just one variable, $h$. People often use the
term *parameter* for something like $x$: a variable whose value we fix,
to focus attention on the remaining variables.

Since $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ is a function of $h$, but undefined at $h=0$,
we can now try to take the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$. If the limit exists,
then $f$ is differentiable for that value of $x$. Here, $h$ is a so-called
dummy or bound variable in the limit expression: the limit, if it exists,
does not depend on $h$, but only the function $f$ and the fixed value $x$.
"Unfixing" the value $x$, we then have a function of $x$, namely $f'(x)$.

In a sense, $f$ itself is a variable in the difference quotient. You can't evaluate $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ until you know what your function $f$ is. Of course, it's a different kind of variable: not a real number, but a function from real numbers to real numbers. So we can even consider the function $f\mapsto f'$, the "derivative function", whose domain is the collection of all differentiable functions.

With that in mind, look at the integral
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx$$
This is a function of $a$, $b$, and $f$. The variable $x$ is again a bound or dummy variable: the integral does not depend on it. In more advanced treatments, you'll often see just $\int f$.

If we fix $a$ and $f$ and just let $b$ vary, we now have a function of one variable, and the famous fundamental theorem of calculus (in one form) says that the derivative of this function is $f$. We can also study $f\mapsto \int f$ as a "function of functions".

The *definition* of the integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ as a limit is considerably more complicated than the definition of the derivative as a limit. The simplest version is the Riemann integral with evenly spaced partitions, and sample points at the right:
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\Delta x$$
where $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_i = a+i\Delta x$. *Inside* the summation symbol we have an expression which is a function of $f$, $x_i$ and $\Delta x$. But the definitions of these in terms of $a$, $b$, $i$, and $n$, makes this a function of $f$, $a$, $b$, $i$, and $n$. Summing on $i$ turns $i$ into a dummy variable. Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ leaves us with a function of $f$, $a$, and $b$, the definite integral.

Comment: Thanks. Is $\Sigma f(x)dx$ which use in integral definition also a kind of function?

Comment: @Russel Riemann integrals are defined as / can be defined as limits of a sequence of real numbers. These are functions $\Bbb N\to\Bbb R$, so, if you like.

Comment: @FShrike Thanks a million. Now I know where I am in calculus. So we use functions all the time we are in derivitive or integral definitions.

Comment: @Russel As long as you know precisely how the limit is defined it doesn’t really matter whether or not you think about things as limits of a sequence of numbers or as limits of a function. If you want to be super formal, most things in maths are encoded with functions and sets anyway

Comment: I've added some more about the integral.

Comment: @FShrike But the limits are all about functions according to its defenition. We use a certain input, so we get a close enough value for our function, Isn't it? My question is raised from this view.